# Issue in applying gradient color on view and button in swift

Tags: swift, colors, gradient

i'm trying to apply gradient color on view and button, but i'm facing an issue that it is not applying on the entire frame of button and view as you can see in screenshot.I have used this code and giving my custom hex values for color,

```
func applyGradient(colours: [UIColor]) -> Void {
    let gradient: CAGradientLayer = CAGradientLayer()
    gradient.frame = self.bounds
    gradient.colors = colours.map { $0.cgColor }
    gradient.startPoint = CGPoint(x : 0.0, y : 0.5)
    gradient.endPoint = CGPoint(x :1.0, y: 1.5)
    self.layer.insertSublayer(gradient, at: 0)
}
```

and applying like this by calling this function,

```
self.headerView.applyGradient(colours: [UIColor.init(hexString: "54F3FF"),UIColor.init(hexString: "43D7FF") ,UIColor.init(hexString: "30B7FF")])
```

Now when i run the app and test it, it looks like this
[image]

[image]

How can i apply gradient to full frame of view and button? What is the mistake in my code?

Comment: It looks like your gradient layer's frame is off, I don't think there are issues with the actual gradient itself

Comment: Try calling your gradient function in viewwillappear method

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this

```
override func viewDidLayoutSubviews() {
        self.headerView.applyGradient(colours: [UIColor.init(hexString: "54F3FF"),UIColor.init(hexString: "43D7FF") ,UIColor.init(hexString: "30B7FF")])
    }
```

Hope this helps

Answer (score 0):

@Junaid Khan,

Try like below,

```
extension UIView {

    func applyGradient(colours: [CGColor], startPoint: CGPoint, endPoint: CGPoint, frame: CGRect) -> Void {

        let gradientLayer = CAGradientLayer()
        gradientLayer.colors = colours
        gradientLayer.startPoint = startPoint
        gradientLayer.endPoint = endPoint
        gradientLayer.frame = frame
        layer.insertSublayer(gradientLayer, at: 0)
    }
}
```

If you have using constraints then call like below on your constraints method,

```
DispatchQueue.main.asyncAfter(deadline: .now() + 1.0) {

            yourView?.applyGradient(colours: [UIColor.red.cgColor, UIColor.yellow.cgColor], startPoint: CGPoint(x: 0, y: 1), endPoint: CGPoint(x: 1, y: 1), frame: (yourView?.bounds)!)
        }
```

Hope it's save your time!

Note: You can convert or get RGB colours by using your hexa color value.

Comment: Thanks i got it fixed.